# Get only date part from the path and this will be exchanged dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to retrieve particular portion from the path and convert that value into date format.

```
\**\Devenvironment\E$\test\Account\20022021\Account_Customer Line_Test_transaction_15022021.xlsx**
```

From the above the above path I want to get only 2002202 and convert this value to date format(YYYY-MM-DD).
Could someone help me on this

Answer (score 0):

This is going to take a few steps. First you can use `PATINDEX` to find the position of the date and time value; then `SUBSTRING` to extract that value. Then you need to use `STUFF` to inject the `'-'` into the string so you can finally `TRY_CONVERT` it with a style code.

I do this using `VALUES` as it find it easier to break the different parts up.

```sql
DECLARE @YourString varchar(100) = '\Devenvironment\E$\test\Account\20022021\Account_Customer Line_Test_transaction_15022021.xlsx';

SELECT *, TRY_CONVERT(date,S.FormattedDate)
FROM (VALUES(@YourString))V(YourString)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(V.YourString,NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[0-3][0-9][0-1][0-9][1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',V.YourString),0),8)))SS(DateString)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(STUFF(STUFF(SS.DateString,5,0,'-'),3,0,'-')))S(FormattedDate);
```

Comment: Thanks Larnu. We can index and substring. But problem for me is this path will be changing dynamically. So I can't use substring function to find the this particular portion. I am not sure how to use this. This path is coming from table column. If you don't mind can you modify it to table column and send it to me. Sorry for asking again

Comment: *"So I can't use substring function to find the this particular portion"* I don't follow what you mean here; `SUBSTRING` is using the value from `PATINDEX` to get the position.. Also it should be more than trivial for you to replace the  first object in the `FROM` with your table instead.

Comment: I got a solution. Thanks